# Custom has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many

I have a `Rule` model that references a `Question` model using a `question_id` field.

The rule `belongs_to` question and the question `has_many` rules.

So, I can do `rule.question.name`.

But, there is also a `show_question_id` field. It should also reference the `Question` model, but that's what I can't figure out.

I'd like to be able to do something like `rule.show_question.name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
belongs_to :show_question, :class_name => 'Question'
```

Rails infers the foreign key and the class name from the name of the association, so you need to tell it to use `Question` rather than the (non-existent) `ShowQuestion`